# Accessing hovered point data series highstock

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a problem in my Angular app. I have to create a graphic with multiple series and show tooltip with x and y values as well as the point id which is different from x and y.

For gather data, i create an array of point object like this :

```
 pointobject = {
     x: data.measurementIds[el.x].date,
     y: el.y,
     id: el.x
    }
```

I push it into my array `points`, and create a temporary series like object. Once this is done, i push it into serie array and add it to my highcharts config object.

And here is the problem : How can i access in tooltip config part the point id currently hovered ?

Comment: If you have disabled dataGrouping, then use (for shared tooltip): `this.points[0].point.options.id`. With enabled dataGrouping you don't have access to id, since a couple of points are grouped into one, and such information isn't available (question is: how to find average of: `"a"`, `"v"` and `"t"` letters?).

Comment: I don't use dataGrouping,  Thanks for your solution, it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to get my id : `this.points[0].point.id`.

I copy/paste Pawel comment for more details:

> If you have disabled dataGrouping, then use (for shared tooltip): `this.points[0].point.options.id.` With enabled dataGrouping you don't have access to id, since a couple of points are grouped into one, and such information isn't available (question is: how to find average of: `"a"`, `"v"` and `"t"` letters?).